# Problem with expanding json data in a column into multiple columns in a dataframe PySpark from Apache Kafka streaming data

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

Dears,

I practise streaming data. I decided to create Apache Kafka.
I would like to read data from KafkaProducer, then I created a Kafka Source for Streaming Queries:

```
df = spark \
  .read \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092") \
  .option("subscribe", topic_name) \
  .load()

df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)").show(truncate=False)
df.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)").printSchema()
```

It works properly:

[image]

I would like to expand this json data in a value column into multpie columns in order to process further this data.
I used this code:

```
json_schema = StructType(
[
    StructField('A', StringType(), True),
    StructField('B', StringType(), True)
]
) 
 json_df = df.selectExpr("cast(value as string) as value")
json_expanded_df = json_df.withColumn("value", from_json(json_df["value"], 
json_schema)).select("value.*") 

json_expanded_df.show()
```

It returns a dataframe, but it has a null values:

[image]

I browsed internet, and I have no idea why it returns NULL values in the dataframe.
Even if I used IntegerType() in a json_schema, the result is the same.

I would appreciate if it someone could advice me how to deal with it.

Comment: 1) `cast(key as string) as value` doesn't make sense to me. Your keys apparently are null. Renaming the key as the value column will keep them as null... 2) We don't know what your records actually look like to know if A and B are correct Schema. Changing the type won't magically fix it.... The databricks blogs have posts on how to process json in Kafka, by the way

Comment: Hi. Yes, it should be "cast(value as string) as value". I have already corrected. Thank you for your advice regarding databricks blogs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It works properly:

Look at the data. Where did A and B come from for the schema you tried to use? If the schema is wrong, you'll get null rows, not an error.

This is the schema you should be using

```
json_schema = StructType([
    StructField('number', IntegerType(), False),
])
```

Then cast the *value* column `as value`, not override it with the key casted result